# RadGridView Summary row counting number of rows and now the values contained within - C#

Tags: c#, radgridview

I'm writing a program and it uses RadGridView - I've got a summary row which I want to total all of the values in a certain column. I have the row setting up correctly however, it only seems to be totalling up the number of rows and now the value contained within.

```
GridViewSummaryItem summaryItem = new GridViewSummaryItem("order_qty", "Total = {0}", GridAggregateFunction.Count);
                GridViewSummaryRowItem summaryRowItem = new GridViewSummaryRowItem();
                summaryRowItem.Add(summaryItem);
                radGridView1.Templates[0].SummaryRowsTop.Add(summaryRowItem);
                btn_generate_pickList.Visible = true;
```

My code for this is above.

I've also included a screen shot of the result given below.

[image]

Will this be happening because the values are strings and need converting?

Comment: Maybe `GridAggregateFunction.Sum` instead of `GridAggregateFunction.Count`

Comment: Wow - How annoying haha! thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by TriV, had to use Sum instead of Count.